# Can I convert DC <=24V to 100-240V AC?

Tags: power-supply

I have this battery pack: https://maxoak.net/products/maxoak-k5-82500mah-cpap-battery-backup
it has 4 female output ports:

- DC 12V/5a
- DC 15V/4a
- DC 24V/4a
- USB 5V/2.4a

I would like to find a solution to charge either, or if I'm lucky, both, of the following devices at separate times. Adapters for both devices say 100-240V ~  50-60Hz. I know I need to convert DC -> AC but is it possible to convert such a low voltage (<= 24) up as high as 100-240?

---

MSI Creator PRO X17
https://www.msi.com/Content-Creation/CreatorPro-X17-A12UX
330W adapter

---

Dell Mobile Precision 5530
https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/precision-15-5530-laptop/preci5530_setupandspec/technical-specifications?guid=guid-aeba1956-9510-43a8-9976-82cc551d38b5&lang=en-us
130 W AC Adapter

Comment: Welcome! Yes, such converters exist, e.g. for camping. However the relative low current of 4 A only limits the power to 96 W maximum. Sorry, asking for product recommendations is off topic here.

Comment: If you search for "car CPAP power bank" and find one that can be charged from a car battery, or at least a PD adapter (which can work from a car battery), then you will find a solution. *I am neither a medical professional nor an electrical engineer.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not really designed to be run at nearly 1C as it's made for a low current load for 8 hours or more.

Max output appears to be 24V/4A, however it will only run that for 3 hours.  This 96 watts is well below the draw of either of those laptops.

I don't gather you have come upon a CPAP battery *for no reason*, so you might want to preserve this unit for its primary purpose.  The certified "1000 uses" is less than 3 years, after all.

I completely agree that "power banks" / "portable power stations" / "solar generators" are *bonkers overpriced* at nearly a buck a watt-hour when the raw batteries are closer to dime a watt-hour at the scrap yard off of EV wrecks.  I suggest looking into the folks particularly on Youtube who build their own power banks out of recovered 18650 batteries, stacks of Nissan Leaf cells, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution might be to use an automotive 12 VDC to 120/240 VAC inverter, for 60 W, and a 24 VDC to 220 VAC inverter, for 96 watts. You can probably run both at the same time.

Comment: I don't think the CPAP battery can have output drawn via the 12V and 24V ports at the same time :(

Answer (score 0):

No. your supply is not powerful enough,  you battery pack has 96W output,  your devices both want more than 100W.